# How to prevent grep from excessive unnecessary memory usage

Tags: linux, grep

I'm greping a hexadecimal pattern (currently a number) from a large binary file (1 TB) with

```
xxd -p /path/to/sda.img | tr -d '\n' | grep -ob '117a0cb17ada1002'
```

and I'm wondering why `grep` uses up to 7 GB RAM and then crashes with error message that no more RAM is available (I have more (16 GB + 8 GB swap), but I get the message). My questions are

- Why does `grep`use so much memory if it doesn't have to memorize anything (search results are printed to stdout immediately (there're no output, so I assume that there're no search results, on a smaller file search results have been displayed immediately)?
- How could I prevent this memory usage if not with `grep` then with an alternative (set of) command(s) fulfilling the same task?

I remove `\n` to have the correct byte offset. I would like to know the position in the file/the one line without delimiter without a lot of calculations (substract number of inserted newlines, etc.).

I'm running `grep` 2.20-3 on Ubuntu 14.10 amd64.

Comment: `sda.img` is an image of whole disk?

Comment: @jimmij Yes, created with `dd`, but that shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: `grep` is probably trying to read an entire line from the pipe. Yes, I know it doesn't need to, for the arguments you provided, but it *would* need to if you said `11.*02`, so maybe it's not smart enough know that this is a special case.

Comment: You run `grep` on huge file without any new lines, as manual states `Though grep expects to do the matching on text, it has no limits on input line length other than available memory`, so your line is `1TB` long and you have only `16BG` + `8GB`. Why do you remove `\n` by the way?

Comment: You may be able to find useful answers at [Binary grep on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4180081/3960947)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You run out of memory because `grep` matches line by line, and you've explicitly removed all newlines in your pipeline:

```
$ xxd -p /path/to/sda.img | tr -d '\n' | grep -ob '117a0cb17ada1002'
```

I assume that what you want to do is to find the byte offset of the particular hexadecimal string within the output of `xxd`, and to be sure that you find it if it's present, you remove newlines (the string may otherwise straddle two lines).

The following `awk` script will match a pattern across consecutive lines and print the position of the first character of the match to the terminal.  It assumes that the input is exactly 60 characters wide (just like the output from `xxd -p` is).

```
{
    if (NR > 1 && offset = match(line $0, pattern)) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", (NR - 2)*60 + offset, pattern);
    }

    line = $0;
}
```

Or, alternatively (but equivalently):

```
NR > 1 {
    if (offset = match(line $0, pattern)) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", (NR - 2)*60 + offset, pattern);
    }
}

{ line = $0 }
```

Testing it on random input data (the search strings that I'm using further down are highlighted in the data):

```
$ xxd -p random.dat | head -n 5
b1a632f5218b1404d9873dc20ae80e687c99c618bfc0f92db007c36c2888
21a99d23914e34510b9ab8e1c2b340cf1e4a0585b788aecbbc64f01a7a52
62e1746ca1fa4ff65d575419522d52169c5d3f9eee0e204979d79634db9b
fa78320eb7b9e072adc53720785fc7b65a1ffb04cc77566686ea74ac00fe
f32afc1539690d0046bc13706404d82112442d4bc447ac95df1fe96cd4bd
```

```
$ xxd -p random.dat | awk -v pattern=b1a632f5 -f script.awk
1: b1a632f5

$ xxd -p random.dat | awk -v pattern=288821a9 -f script.awk
57: 288821a9

$ xxd -p random.dat | awk -v pattern=ac00fef3 -f script.awk
235: ac00fef3
```

Running this on a 1 terabyte large file will be slow, no matter what. It may (possibly) be sped up by giving the `-c 256` option to `xxd` (and changing 60 to 256 in the `awk` script accordingly) to reduce the number of pattern matches, but the data on each line will by necessity be matched twice none the less (once together with the previous line, and once together with the next line).